# regex for removing curly brackets with nested curly brackets

Tags: c#, regex

This is my string: `"This Is {{ dsfdf  {{dsfsd}} ewrwrewr }} My Result"`.

I want to remove the outer curly brackets with their content. 
The result should be `"This Is My Result"`.

This is my best shot at the moment:

```
Text = Regex.Replace(Text, "{{([^}]*)}}", String.Empty);
```

but it doesn't work well. I get `"This Is ewrwrewr }} My Text"`

Perhaps it should be solved with Balance Matching...

I would be **very** appreciate if someone could help me solve it, because although many tries I couldn't do it myself.

Comment: What should the result of "a{{b}}c}}" be? - "ac}}"?, "a" or an error?

Comment: Does this really need to be solved with a regex?  A simple iterative solution would probably be faster and easier to write and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple but slow way is to apply the regex multiple times until there are no more changes:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "This Is {{ dsfdf {{dsfsd}} ewrwrewr }} My Result";

        Regex regex = new Regex("{{({?}?[^{}])*}}");
        int length;
        do
        {
            length = s.Length;
            s = regex.Replace(s, "");
        } while (s.Length != length);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
}
```

Comment: this one works great! thank you for your fast answer...
i didn't know what a geniuses are hanging around here :))

Answer (score 1):

What do You think about:

```
string test = "This Is {{ dsfdf {{dsfsd}} \n jkhhjk ewrwrewr }} My Result";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(test, "{{.*}}", String.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline));
```

Version without "Regex":

```
string test = "This Is {{ dsfdf {{dsfsd}} \n jkhhjk ewrwrewr }} My Result";
int startIndex = test.IndexOf("{");
int length = test.LastIndexOf("}") - startIndex + 1;
Console.WriteLine(test.Replace(test.Substring(startIndex, length), String.Empty));
```

Comment: If your real case is as simple as your example, this should be fine!

Comment: Wouldn't this also remove stuff across bracket groups? {{ 1 {{ 2 }} 3 }} 4 {{ 5 }} <- removes 4 also?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply...!
it works! but... i didn't mention it before... my mistake.
it has multiple lines it. a better example would be:
"This Is {{ dsfdf {{dsfsd}} \n jkhhjk ewrwrewr }} My Result"

Comment: @Tom: You can add one more parameter to make this work with new lines: "RegexOptions.Singleline".

Comment: Glenn: Tom presented an example for which I gave the simplest solution(as for me). My solution doesn't handle all possible cases ;).

Comment: And by "work", I mean that it will eat the entire scetion from the first {{ to the last }}, which might not be what you want.